# How to create a zip archive of a directory and save the zip file in same directory?

Tags: python, zip

hi i want to create a zip archive of a directory and save the zip file in same directory

i try to use `make_archive` from `shuttle` lib

but the zip file goes to wrong path

this is my code:

[mycode pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gzm7A.png)

```py
def makearchive():
    make_archive(
    'zipfile_name', 
    'zip',           # the archive format - or tar, bztar, gztar 
    root_dir=None,   # root for archive - current working dir if None
    base_dir=None)   # start archiving from here - cwd if None too

def downloadProject(user,projectName):
    projectPath = os.path.join(BASE_DIR/'UsersProjects'/user,projectName)
    buildPath = os.path.join(projectPath,'build.zip')
    if os.path.isfile(buildPath):
        os.remove(buildPath)
        # shutil.make_archive('build', 'zip', projectPath)
        makearchive(projectPath)
    else:
        # shutil.make_archive('build', 'zip', projectPath)
        makearchive(projectPath)
```

what i can do ?

Answer (score 0):

from what I see you are not using the projectPath variable since your makearchive function does not receive any argument, I leave you a code example of how I would do it

```
def makearchive(projectpath=None):
make_archive(
'zipfile_name', 
'zip',           # the archive format - or tar, bztar, gztar 
root_dir=projectPath,   # root for archive - current working dir if None
base_dir=None)   # start archiving from here - cwd if None too
```